# при запуске локального сервера, открываются ссылки на папки с кодом

Tags: php, html, css, localhost

[image]

при запуске ospanel, а именно мой хост, открывается это, это норма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас отсутсвуют исполняемые файлы `index.html` или `index.php` это нормально. Показывает директорию. Локальный сервер ищет корневой файл входа и не находит его там.